# Use Chef to ensure a user environment variable is deleted but not a system variable on Windows

Tags: windows, environment-variables, chef-infra

I'm writing a chef script to install nvm for windows. I've just had a problem where the system ends up with a User and a System variable for `NVM_HOME`

`env 'NVM_HOME' do
  action :delete
end`

the above would presumable remove both

How can I amend my chef script to ensure the system variable is kept but the user variable is removed if present?

Comment: I think for this you'll have to make a small script in powershell, see [here](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff730964.aspx) for a starting point.

Comment: yes, was assuming I could shell out and do something like `REG delete HKCU\Environment /F /V FOOBAR` but wondered if it was built in and I was misunderstanding the chef docs

Comment: I assume playing with the user SSID and `registry_key` resource this is doable, I will need to target KHU/<SSID>/... but that should be doable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the user environment variable is the user running chef and not another user you can use the [`registry_key`](https://docs.chef.io/resource_registry_key.html) resource to ensure the values are deleted (untested example):

```
registry_key "HKCU\\Environment" do
  values [{:name => 'NVM_HOME'},{:name => 'NVM_SYMLINK'}]
  action :delete
end
```

If you wish to change another user variable you can have a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22945786/access-the-registry-of-another-user-with-chef)

Answer (score 0):

Did this in the end

`[
  'NVM_HOME',
  'NVM_SYMLINK'
].each do |key|
  execute "ensure nvm has not added #{key} user variables" do
    command "REG delete HKCU\\Environment /F /V #{key}"
    only_if { registry_key_exists? "HKCU\\Environment\\#{key}" }
  end
end`

probably not the best way but it ran :)

Comment: yep, that's the only case I need it for.

Comment: Then the `registry_key` [resource](https://docs.chef.io/resource_registry_key.html) would avoid the need of a guard.

Comment: by all means add it as an answer :)